# How to 'pin' objects in XCode 7.1

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7.1

I have an existing iPad *portrait mode* app (XCode 7.1) that I am trying to add *landscape mode* to.  I am trying to follow one of Ray Wenderlic's outdated (2013) tutorials for using Auto Layout.

At one point, he says:

> Hold down the ⌘ key while you click on the two views on the top (the green and yellow ones), so that both are selected. From Xcode’s Editor menu, select Pin\Widths Equally:

which doesn't exist in the Editor menu.  I have looked in SO and Google and found nothing regarding XC 7.1 and pinning.    So *how* do I pin objects in XCode 7.1?

Comment: What's the point of downvoting and voting to close without an explanation of why?

Comment: The close vote is due to the question "Does anybody know where I can find a newer, better tutorial on Auto Layout?". I'd guess the down vote likewise. SO guidelines state that asking for recommendations to offsite resources are off topic. If you remove that clause you'll have a valid question regarding the pin. Btw Erica Sadun's Auto Layout Demystified is excellent and well worth the price.

Comment: Thank you Max... I appreciate the response (I had forgotten about the "recommendations" prohibition);  Question has been updated...  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bottom toolbar in Interface Builder. Click "Pin" -> check "Equal Width" -> "Add Constraints".
Screenshot:

[image]